# Android SDK data retrieval from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS Android SDK to communicate with DynamoDB. I have following table defined in DynamoDB:

Name: BeaconPosition
HashKey: BeaconKey (String)
Attributes: BeaconName (String), BeaconAccuracy (Number)

Data loading to this table is working fine but I am struggling to retrieve all rows from this table in my app. I went through AWS DynamoDB documents and tried following two ways to retrieve table rows:

```
//Initializing dynamoDB client in the constructor of my data mapper.
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            applicationContext, // get the context for the current activity
            "us-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 //Region
    );
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);


//1st way of retrieving table rows.
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName("BeaconPosition");
ScanResult result = ddbClient.scan(scanRequest);
for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()){
//code to read each item from the table.
}

//2nd way of retrieving table rows.
Condition hashKeyCondition = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString()).withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS("BeaconKeyXXXXX-XXXXX"));
Map<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
keyConditions.put("BeaconKey", hashKeyCondition);
Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = null;
do {
    QueryResult queryResult=null;
    QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest().withTableName("BeaconPosition").withKeyConditions(keyConditions).withExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);
queryResult = ddbClient.query(queryRequest);  

for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : queryResult.getItems()) {
//Code to read item and load domain object.
}
lastEvaluatedKey = queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();
} while (lastEvaluatedKey != null);
```

---

The problem: I am debugging this code block and observed that the system hangs on following code line in both of the ways I stated above. Debugger never returns from executing this code line. I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, restarting Android Studio, uninstalling/reinstalling the app on my device but nothing helped. I have already verified that the table names and attributes are correctly specified. I have also tried providing an incorrect/unavailable table name but the behavior remains as it is.

For the 1st way:

```
ScanResult result = ddbClient.scan(scanRequest);
```

For the 2nd way:

```
queryResult = ddbClient.query(queryRequest);
```

UPDATE: I am doing this data retrieval logic in a background thread.

Comment: How many record you have in the table?

Comment: are you sure you are not trying to retrieve too much data from scan and query (comparing to the provisioning throughput you set on your data table). Query can  be fast only when your items are effectively placed over partitions in case you didn't use Rank Key for effective filtering.

Comment: Harshal - Its a test table. I have only 7 rows loaded in the table.

Comment: Nick - Yes, its not too much data as there exist only 7 records in the table. I am a beginner to AWS so testing a simple retrieval for now.